# Re-use unnamed namespace functions in multiple cpp files

Tags: c++

Currently, I have one A.cpp file having some functions defined in unnamed namespace

```
// A.cpp

namespace {
void foo1() {}
void foo2() {}
}
```

Now I have another B.cpp file which wants to re-use foo1() and foo2(). What is the best practice? Shall we just have a new Common.h file for foo1 and foo2, and then ask A.cpp/B.cpp to include Common.h

```
// Common.h
namespace {
void foo1() {}
void foo2() {}
}

// A.cpp
#include <Common.h>

// B.cpp
#include <Common.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions defined in an anonymous namespace in a .cpp file are like private functions. They are not meant to be reused in another .cpp file.

If you find that they can be reused by another .cpp file, those functions need to be declared in a .h file and defined in the appropriate .cpp file.

Whether you declare the functions in Common.h, A.h, or B.h, depends entirely up to you. The names of the functions in your posted code don't give much clue as to which .h file will be best to contain those declarations.

If you declare them in Common.h, I suggest that you implement them in Common.cpp.

If you declare them in A.h, I suggest that you implement them in A.cpp.

If you declare them in B.h, I suggest that you implement them in B.cpp.